# Riak cluster offline when option search turned on and mochiweb+webmachine web server Internal error

Tags: database, cluster-computing, riak

I am new to Riak and I have two questions

1. When I turn search = on the node crashes and never comes back online.
2. I get the mochiweb+webmachine web server issue when going to the browser links at the port number but /stats and /mapred shows. Not sure if it is running, how do I get started here?

Comment: envymike can you provide more details on your environment? What OS are you running on, did you compile your own Riak or are you using Basho's binaries, etc.?

Comment: Simply put... I am new so I didn't realize two basic things. 1. I ran out of memory which was the issue with search = on maxing out. 2. No bucket/data created to access these links which I am trying to learn in setting up in the first place. Thanks.